# How to design plugin architecture where plugins populate different parts of a web page?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I'm trying to design a system of plugins that populate different components of a web page, where each plugin is responsible for its own view or visualization of the underlying data (could be stock data, for example for 1000 stocks).
I need help coming up with a design that's simple, but properly separates the MVC components . I feel my current design below improperly mixes in html throughout, and makes it difficult to change the over-all layout of the main index.html page. **I'm not sure how to fix this while keeping the code simple and lite-weight, yet allowing each plugin maximum flexibility in terms of what it puts on its section of the page. 
What are the best-practice ideas / libraries for doing this?**

One thought I had was to generate json that is consumed by pre-defined javascript/html widgets. **Are there python libraries that provide an architecture for this (and maybe some nice widgets for data presentation)?**

To give some context, these plugins will be part of an app that provides a simple web-based way for scientists to go through the results of a data analysis pipeline. 
The pipeline generates between 1 and 1000 directories (one per experimental sample) each containing 5 to 20 standard and custom file **types**. My python app crawls these directories and generates a web page where each type of result can be viewed across all samples (either in some summary format, or by flipping/scrolling through samples).

[1] http://effbot.org/zone/metaclass-plugins.htm

Thanks
-Ben

Ps. My current pseudocode is:

```
    plugin_registry = []   

    class FileTypeHandlerPlugin:
        __metaclass__ = register_plugin     # based on effbot.org post [1]

        # Base class's methods won't contain code. Just included for explanation.

        def handle_files(self, all_file_paths):
            # 1. pick out the files of your type
            # 2. parse the files and create data structure to use by get_html(..)
            # 3. maybe generate some files and summary graphs (eg. summary_graph.png)

        def get_html(self):
            # get the html
            result = """
              <img src="summary_graph.png">
              <table>
                 <tr><td>sample</td><td>value1</td><td>value2...
                 <tr><td>s1 ...
              </table>
            """
            return result

        def get_heading(self):  
            return "some heading"        

    class FileType1Handler(FileTypeHandlerPlugin):

        def get_html(self)
            return "<pre>%s</pre>" % self.quality_string....            

        def get_heading(self):
            return "Quality Scores"


        def handle_files(self, all_file_paths):
            self.quality_score_files = [p for p in all_file_paths if p.endswith(".qual")]
            ...


    def main():
        all_file_paths = []
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("."):
            all_file_paths.extend(filenames)

        for plugin in plugin_registry:
            plugin.handle_files(all_file_paths)

        f = open("index.html", "w")
        for plugin in plugin_registry:
            f.write( "<h3>" + plugin.get_heading() + "</h3>")
            f.write( plugin.get_html() )
        f.close()

        webserver.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps seeing this in the classic [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) paradigm.

- Your *model* should retrieve the data from the files.
- Your *view* should decorate the data however they see fit
- Your *controller* should link the views with the right models and handle stuff like user input.

In this case, this would mean that your plugins are mainly *view plugins*, which would register themselves through a *controller*.

In your current code, it looks like the view and controller especially are a bit intertwined. I would do something like this pseudocode (with a cleaner layout with modules and stuff):

```
class CSVHandler():
    # A view plugin, which can output HTML.
    def handle(data):
         output = ''
         for file in data:
            if data.type != 'csv':
                continue

            # Do stuff into output

         return output

view_plugins = []

def register_view_plugin(plugin):
     view_plugins.append(plugin)

register_view_plugin(SummaryHandler())
register_view_plugin(CSVHandler())
register_view_plugin(PDFHandler())

def render(data):
   output = '\n'.join([x.handle(data) for x in view_plugins])

@app.route('/show/<sample_id>')
def show(sample_id):
    # This is the controller
    data = get_data(sample_id)

    return render(data)


def get_data(sample_id):
    # Return a model of the data.
    return [{'type': 'csv', 'content': '...'}, 
            {'type': 'pdf', 'author': 'Foo', 'content': '...'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you have any suggestions for what handle(..) methods should return (html? javascript?) and how render(..) should turn that into a final html page? Are there python libraries that provide data structures or methods for generating html or javascript components?

Answer (score 0):

Design a plugin Interface in the framework which shall be implemented by the plugin web apps. And with dependency injection you can load the plugin web apps during runtime and validate the plugins whether they have implemented the interface correctly. Thus, the correct plugins will be loaded during runtime.